# xcode - How to show rounded value of settings?

Tags: xcode

I'm working on Xcode 5.0.2. I added some value to 'Header search path', but it is not shown on textbox now. Could anyone tell me how to expand its rounded string to read whole value?

Comment: Double-clicking works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see them in a build log after '-I' compiler flag.